# Sophos Intelix Static file analysis - html

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

What about code of Submit a file for static analysis - HTML create on Insomnia?
https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/analysis/file/static.html
describe only 3!

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand the question. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: https://www.sophos.com/en-us/labs/intelix.aspx follow by video on this page I found (Static File Analysis - HTML) but not see on api link! What api link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Static File Analysis - HTML' option that is shown on our video refers to calling the [static file analysis](https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/analysis/file/static.html) part of the API and including the parameter `report_format=html`. This will ensure that the response from the API is given in HTML rather than the default of JSON.

You mention that our API documentation shows 3 submissions (1 post and 2 gets) each of these submissions will accept the `report_format` option which has two options (JSON which is the default and HTML). This has lead to the 6 items that you can see in Insomnia in our video.

Comment: Is it true? POST https://{{ region  }}.{{ base_url  }}/analysis/file/static/v1/{{ file }}?report_format=html

Comment: It is slightly more complicated than what you are suggesting. With a POST request the URL is `https://{{ region }}.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1/ ` the file and the report_format are part of the body of the request.

Comment: There are a number of tools that you can use to compose requests using to try out the API, one of my personal favourite's is Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/), there is a good post on how to send a POST request here https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/